# Debian server planting. Error logs : xmlrpc.php

Tags: wordpress, debian, xml-rpc, error-log

my server www.djula.fr planting and I need to reboot all the time.

I connect to SSH to see the error logs, and I see this:

[The error log screenshot](http://michael-pathe.com/stacks/error%20log.jpg)

What does it mean ?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: You mean crashing, not planting. Also post the error here, do not link to a screenshot.

Comment: Does it gives you some good vegetables at least? Joke apart, you should ask this on serverfault, not here. And you should paste the error message in your question in addition of the screenshot.